# What's different between -d.lib and just normal like SFML-system.lib?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sfml

I'm just starting to learn SFML with Visual Studio. I am faced with problems that my image doesn't loaded with `texture.loadFromFile("path")`. I found that someone solved this by changing every sfml-~~.lib in linker-input-additional dependency, to sfml-~~-d.lib. So I changed it and solved it! Now I'm wondering what makes the difference: What's "-d"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-d is the debug library.

As stated on their installation tutorial:

*It is important to link to the libraries that match the configuration: "sfml-xxx-d.lib" for Debug, and "sfml-xxx.lib" for Release. A bad mix may result in crashes.*

[SFML and Visual Studio](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php)